# SQL to search many to many relationship with acts_as_tsearch

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, full-text-search

I'm using the acts_as_tsearch plugin for rails to do full text searching with Postgresql.

They give an example of multi table search here:
http://code.google.com/p/acts-as-tsearch/wiki/ActsAsTsearchMethod

But that only does a one-to-many relationship.  I'm trying to get it to also search a many-to-many relationship (has_and_belongs_to_many or habtm) for tags on a page.  But my SQL isn't advanced enough.

Here is what I've got so far:

```
  acts_as_tsearch :vectors => {
    :fields => {
      "a" => {:columns => ["pages.name"], :weight => 1.0},
      "b" => {:columns => ["pages.description"], :weight => 0.2},
      "c" => {:columns => ["tags.name"], :weight => 0.2}
    },
    :tables => {
      :tags => {
        :from => "tags INNER JOIN taggings ON tags.id = taggings.tag_id",
        :where => "((taggings.taggable_type = 'Page') AND (taggings.taggable_id = ???.id) AND ((taggings.context = 'tags')))"
      }
    }
  }
```

I'm not sure how to reference the page id (where I put the ???).

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you explain what a taggable_id is used for?

Comment: Good question, sorry I should have explained.  It's polymorphic so taggable_id refers to any model which can have tags.  In this case it could be called page_id since only my pages have tags, but they made it polymorphic so any model can have tags.

Basically, the "taggings" table hold the ids for pages and tags to connect the many-to-many relationship.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the SQL behind this would be:

```
select
    p.name,
    p.description,
    t.name
from
    pages p
    inner join taggings ts on
        p.page_id = ts.taggable_id
        and ts.taggable_type = 'Page'
        and ts.context = 'tags'
    inner join tags t on
        ts.tag_id = t.tag_id
```

So, your Ruby would look like:

```
acts_as_tsearch :vectors => {
  :fields => {
    "a" => {:columns => ["p.name"], :weight => 1.0},
    "b" => {:columns => ["p.description"], :weight => 0.2},
    "c" => {:columns => ["t.name"], :weight => 0.2}
  },
  :tables => {
    :tags => {
      :from => "pages p
        inner join taggings ts on
            p.page_id = ts.taggable_id
            and ts.taggable_type = 'Page'
            and ts.context = 'tags'
        inner join tags t on
            ts.tag_id = t.tag_id"
    }
  }
}
```

This is the standard way to get through a many-to-many table--just start at one table, join the mapping, and then join the other table. Voila! Many-to-many results!